# Web3 create account from mnemonic + passphrase

Tags: web3js, javascript, hd-wallets, bip39

I'm trying to create an ethereum account using web3-js by providing a mnemonic + passphrase (created with BIP39-js) but can't seem to find an implementation of web3.eth.accounts.create() that accepts both the mnemonic and the passphrase.

Is it not supported or am I missing something on how to implement it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it with [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-advanced.html#creating-instances):

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const mnemonic = await ethers.HDNode.entropyToMnemonic(ethers.utils.randomBytes(16));
const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
```

P.S.

Here is a [community](https://gitter.im/lime-tech-talks/Lobby?source=orgpage) you can find ask more questions about it:

Comment: In the meantime it is: `ethers.utils.HDNode.entropyToMnemonic`

Comment: OP mentioned mnemonic + passphrase: there's no passphrase in there. how is this the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone comes here later, in the recent version of [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io), `HDNODE` has been moved to the `utils` method. So, in modification to @George's answer above;

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const mnemonic = await ethers.utils.HDNode.entropyToMnemonic(ethers.utils.randomBytes(16));
const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ethers Lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

newWallet = async () => {
    let password = prompt("Password");

    if (password) {
      var randomSeed = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();

      console.log(randomSeed.mnemonic);
      console.log(randomSeed.address);

      function callback(progress) {
        console.log("Encrypting: " + parseInt(progress * 100) + "% complete");
      }

      let encryptPromise = randomSeed.encrypt(password, callback);

      encryptPromise.then(function (json) {
        console.log(json);
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

web3.js doesn't have this tool installed natively. We use the HD Wallet Provider for this.

Check: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider

You solve this in Web3 as follows:

Install:

```
npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider
```

Don't forget to install web3.js and truffle

The code below goes through the generation of all accounts of a mnemonic

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const mnemonicPhrase = "mnemonicPhrase here"; 
const urlRPC = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org"; 

const Web3Instance = require('web3');
const web3instance = new Web3Instance(new Web3Instance.providers.HttpProvider(urlRPC));

//HD Wallet Provider loads by default only 10 accounts
//We change the limit to as many accounts as we want
//You cannot run the loop below for i greater than 10, because for
const limit = 50;

async function getAccount() {

  provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: mnemonicPhrase,
    numberOfAddresses: limit,
    providerOrUrl: urlRPC,
    addressIndex: 0,

    });

  //HDWalletProvider is compatible with Web3
  //Use it at Web3 constructor, just like any other Web3 Provider
  const web3 = new Web3(provider);

  for (let i = 0; i < limit - 1; i ++) {

    var get = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    var address = get[i];
    var balanceETH = await web3instance.eth.getBalance(address)

    //Checking the adress
    console.log(address);
    console.log(balanceETH);

  }

}

getAccount();
```

You can check about retrieving the private key here: [Retrieving the private/ public key with web3js for a specific wallet provided by truffle/hdwallet-provider](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102090/retrieving-the-private-public-key-with-web3js-for-a-specific-wallet-provided-by)