# The same wallet address on the Mainnet Ethereum network and on the Polygon network. Are these two different wallets with two different owners?

Tags: blockchain, transactions, addresses, polygon, mainnet

I want to transfer some matic (Polygon network) to an Ethereum wallet address I know. But I don't know the address of this wallet on the Polygon network, I know its address on the Ethereum Mainnet.
The address of this wallet can be found at etherscan.io and can also be found at polygonscan.com.

Question: Is the same wallet address on different networks the same wallet with the same owner, or are they different wallets with different owners?

P.S. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time its same. But not always.
Polygon Mainnet have made its own chain, which is seperate from Ethereum chain.

When we create wallet by wallet providers like metamask the wallet address of ethereum polygon BNB etc are same.

But when we create wallet with codes like `Web3.eth.accounts.create()` (web3JS web3Py) one wallet address is created with a perticular Chain. that address is not for other chains, e.g. A wallet address created at matic is not available at ethereum.

In deep down: metamask create wallet with memonic key + passphrase, when u add new EVM based chain on metamask with same account, it simply perform `createAccount(memonic,passphrase)`.

There are so much memonic combinations, that getting same memonic is almost impossible.

more to read:
[Web3 create account from mnemonic + passphrase](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52370/web3-create-account-from-mnemonic-passphrase)

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that yes. Both polygon and ethereum use the same format for wallet addresses, and with the same private key you could sign transactions for both chains.

Answer (score 0):

MetaMask wallet enables one to have same address on Polygon and Ethereum Main Network.

You only have to take caution and remember to select the preferred network before carrying out a transaction especially on centralized exchanges.